# How do I input a string into a char* variable allocated using malloc?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that works with a string, converts it into an array of words, and stuff.
Initially, I wrote it like

```
main()
{   char a[100];
    char *s;
    int len;
    getchar();
    printf("\nEnter string: ");
    gets(a);
    for(len=0;*(a+len)!='\0';len++);
    printf("\nLength is %d\n",len);
    s=malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
    s=a;
    //Rest of the program
}
```

and I used the string s for the rest of the program. It worked fine. The rest of the program separates words and prints them, and I could see the output.

Then I thought a was redundant and wrote

```
main()
{   char *s;
    int app_len;
    printf("\nEnter length of string(Approximate more than necessary): ");
    scanf("%d",&app_len);
    getchar();
    printf("\nEnter string: ");
    s=malloc(sizeof(char)*app_len);
    fgets(s,app_len+1,stdin);
    //Rest of the program
}
```

When I ran the second version, and gave a valid input, there was no output, the command-prompt returned to the windows-equivalent of the dollar prompt.

Is something wrong with the way I used malloc; or fgets?
After allocating memory space using malloc, am I only allowed to assign a value to it, and not to take input?

EDIT: Here's all my code. It works now :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void copy(char *dest,char *s)
{   int i;
    for(i=0;*(s+i)!='\0';i++)
        *(dest+i)=*(s+i);
    *(dest+i)='\0';
}   
int comp(char *s1,char *s2)
{   int i;
    for(i=0;!(*(s1+i)=='\0'||*(s2+i)=='\0');i++)
        if(*(s1+i)!=*(s2+i))
            return -1;
    return 0;
}   
int length(char *s)
{   int i;
    for(i=0;*(s+i)!='\0';i++);
    return i;
}   
main()
{   char b[20][20],words[20][20],unique[20][20],non[20][20];
    int i,j,k,len,no_of_words, c,count[100],w=0,u=0,nu=0;
    int mem = 64;
    char *s = malloc(mem);
    printf("\nEnter string : ");
    fgets(s, mem, stdin);
    while(s[length(s) - 1] != '\n')  //checks if we ran out of space
    {   mem *= 2;
        s = realloc(s, mem); //double the amount of space
        fgets(s + mem / 2 - 1, mem / 2 + 1, stdin);//read the rest (hopefully) of the line into the new space.
    }
    len=length(s);
    *(s+len--)='\0';
    printf("%s",s);
    for(i=0,j=0,k=0;i<len&&*(s+i)!='\0'&&*(s+i)!='\n';i++)
    {   if(*(s+i)==' ')
        {   *(*(b+j)+k)='\0';
            j++;
            k=0;
        }
        else
        {   
            *(*(b+j)+k)=*(s+i);//jth word, position k
            k++;
        }
    }
    *(*(b+j)+k)='\0';
    free(s);
    no_of_words=j+1;
    for(i=0;i<no_of_words;i++)
    {   for(j=0,c=0;j<w;j++)
        {   if(comp(*(b+i),*(words+j))==0)
                c++;
        }
        if(c==0)
        {   copy(*(words+w),*(b+i));
            w++;
        }
    }   
    for(j=0;j<w;j++)
    {   for(i=0,c=0;i<no_of_words;i++)
        {   if(comp(*(b+i),*(words+j))==0)
                c++;
        }
        if(c!=0)
        {   copy(*(non+nu),*(words+j));
            count[nu]=c;
            nu++;
        }
        if(c==1)
        {   copy(*(unique+u),*(words+j));
            u++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0,c=0;i<nu;i++)
        if(count[i]!=1)
            c++;
    printf("\nTotal no. of words = %d\n",no_of_words);
    printf("No. of distinct words = %d\n",w);
    printf("No. of distinct unique words = %d\n",u);
    printf("No. of distinct non-unique words = %d\n",c);
    printf("\nUnique words:\n");
    for(i=0;i<u;i++)
    {   printf("%s\n",*(unique+i));
    }
    printf("\nNon-unique words:\n");
    for(i=0;i<nu;i++)
        if(count[i]!=1)
            printf("%s\tFrequency=%d\n",*(non+i),count[i]);
    printf("\nList of all words and their frequencies:\n");         
    for(i=0;i<nu;i++)
            printf("%s\tFrequency=%d\n",*(non+i),count[i]); 
}
```

Comment: You can omit the `sizeof(char)` in malloc. It's defined as 1.

Comment: you have memory leak `s=a;` use `strcpy()` instead, avoid  using  `gets()` use `fget()`

Comment: You are potentially overflowing your buffer. If the buffer length is `app_len`, then you may only input `app_len-1` characters into the string and the argument to `fgets` should also be `app_len`.

Comment: `s = strpy(malloc(len+1), a);`

Comment: I am getting correct output from your program.. How are you printing your output?

Comment: @gmorrow leaving `sizeof(char)` as is. it is good practice. you never know if another architecture defines char to be more then 1 byte.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan memory leak is introduced not calling `free(s)` in the second implementation. `s=a` is valid as it assigns the address of a to s which will hold the pointer to the string. using `strcpy` in first implementation will case segmentation fault as you have no space attached to s, thus the copy is invalid.

Comment: @yay how did you print your string? It looks like your malloc and string gets are fine. I'm wondering if you have corrupted the string buffer location later on with another pointer maybe. Using malloc is tricky as 1. it is hard to maintain and can introduce memory overload which may in turn caused your incorrect output. 2. it may introduce memory leak if you do not call free() to garbage collect the memory space.

Comment: @Xephon I thought it was the C standard that forces sizeof(char) to be exactly 1. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first variant you are losing the just created field of s. And it works only until length(s)<100.

The second variant is OK for me. Maybe only put app_len+1 to both malloc() and fgets().

But better use dynamic reading:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main() {
  int mem = 64;
  char *str = malloc(mem);
  fgets(str, mem, stdin);
  while(str[strlen(str) - 1] != '\n') { //checks if we ran out of space
    mem *= 2;
    str = realloc(str, mem); //double the amount of space
    fgets(str + mem / 2 - 1, mem / 2 + 1, stdin); //read the rest (hopefully) of the line into the new space.
  }
  printf("%s", str);
}
```

Comment: Whoa! That's utopian, except for how many times the loop runs, maybe. When I type `printf("%s", str);`, the code works, even my second version works(i changed `app_len` to `app_len+1`. I think something's wrong with the way I'm printing my output, like @Xephon and @DeepikaSethi said.

Comment: @yay Your code works only up to the length of 100. You are working really with a, only rename it to s. And memory that you gave to s, is lost. Memory leak!

Comment: Well, weirdly, the first variant works, but the second variant doesn't, and neither does the one you wrote. (I only give inputs less than 100 characters long). Am I allowed to post the rest of my program as well? I seriously have no idea where I'm going wrong.

Comment: It works now! I didn't do anything much. I'm not allowed to use string functions, so I wrote a function length()-
`int length(char *s)
{ int i;
 for(i=0;*(s+i)!='\0';i++);
 return i;
} 
main()
{ int i, len;int mem = 64;
 char *s = malloc(mem);
 fgets(s, mem, stdin);
 while(s[length(s) - 1] != '\n') 
 { 
  mem *= 2;
  s = realloc(s, mem);
  fgets(s + mem / 2 - 1, mem / 2 + 1, stdin);
 }
   len=length(s);
 *(s+len--)='\0';
        //rest of the code
}`

Comment: Well, it's the same thing you wrote except that I used

`int length(char *s) { int i; for(i=0;*(s+i)!='\0';i++); return i; }`

and then

`len=length(s);
*(s+len--)='\0';`

Comment: What is the sense of the last? you are looking for \0 and then are putting it in the body at its own position. Put normal code, in question. Put comments there - for yourself, you need it, or you are lost in your own code.

Comment: Erm, I printed the string character by character (along with its index number) and noticed there was an extra character with nothing in it. Hence the last. I did put comments on my code, I removed it because my comment on stackoverflow was too big.

Comment: Wasn't this 'nothing' the '\n'? I don't know about any limits on question size :-)

Comment: @yay Sorry for my forgetfullness. Welcome to StackOverflow and +1 for a decent question.

Comment: Thank you! I realised that if I had just used '\n' to check if a string has terminated instead of '\0' everywhere, I wouldn't need the `*(s+len--)='\0';`

Comment: @yay You are welcome :-). Yes, when getting a line with \n at the end, we have the real end one symbol or two symbol before \0. It also could behave differently on different systems.